# Problem with a Parse Error in Google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

i've a little question about javascript code in GTM, i've a parse error with this code

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
radios.forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false));
function handleChange(e) {
  return(e.target.value);
}
```

Can u help me please :)

Comment: I've a " Parse error. primary expression expected "

Comment: I tried to get the title of my button when i clicked on it

Comment: Hum okay, can u show my prob ?

Comment: Actually i tried to get the button's information when i clicked on it (simple quizz which switch pages when i select a reponse)

Comment: as I said, `return` in an event handler makes no sense ... where is the value going to "return" to?

Comment: I added my real prob

Comment: the second answer

Comment: no, it's a my real prob

Comment: then put it in a QUESTION

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is not quite how you listen for a click in GTM.

While you certainly can do it, it makes no sense since GTM was not implied to do it. You're not supposed to have callbacks in GTM variables and expect them to work. The value of each variable is estimated on a certain GTM trigger. You introduce certain async element there by relying on a listener. Also... I'm not sure how good GTM is with ES6 syntax. I still keep to ES5 in GTM and Launch.

Here how I suggest you do it:

1. Create a click trigger. Use your click selector in the click trigger to limit it to "Some Clicks" Like so:
   [image]
2. Now use this trigger with your tag. You will want to reference your clicked element value in the tag, however. For it:
3. Create a custom js variable returning your value like so:
   [image]
4. Now just reference your CJS variable in the value or wherever you want it.